# I can't get a div to reload on click without reloading the entire page

Tags: jquery

I know that there are other posts like this but after going through them I still can't figure out how to use ajax to reload a div on my page without refreshing the entire page.

Comment: Is #cart a button inside a form?

Comment: don't use code snippets if they don't add any value to your question

Comment: Add return false in the end of onclick. It will prevent common link behavior - reloading page.

Comment: @opportunityr I believe what mic4ael meant what that you should include a [mcve] in your question, but you don't need to use the runnable stack snippet feature unless the code actually can be run to show an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work you must include the URL that will provide the response you are trying to load into your div.

```
$( "#cart" ).click(function() {
    $( "#drawer-indiv-product" ).load( "some-url.html #drawer-indiv-product");
});
```

This is from the load() documentation: http://api.jquery.com/load/, the URL parameter is required.

Edit:
You can use something like this to find out more about the data you are receiving:

```
$( "#cart" ).click(function() {
    $( "#drawer-indiv-product" ).load( "some-url.html #drawer-indiv-product", function(response, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "error") {
            console.log(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
        }
        else {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Don't forget `return false` to prevent common link behavior.

Comment: @CRover Does the response (URL you are requesting) contain the element you are asking for? "#drawer-indiv-product"...and if it does, does it have the additional elements you are expecting? Take a look at the documentation, there are additional parameters that you can use to find out more about the response you are receiving from your request.

Comment: Looks like you haven't provided us the rest of js code. With `e`.

Comment: @CRover Take a look at the edit I made on the answer, there is now a bit of code to debug the response from the url. If the content is disappearing, it's probably coming back empty or maybe the request is not receiving a 200 status.

Comment: @CRover Glad that helped to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `load` method incorrectly. According to the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/) you can load a fragment from the remote document but in order to do that you need to use the correct syntax. For example:

```
$( "#drawer-indiv-product" ).load("/resource/load.html #drawer-indiv-product");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use load correctly. In addition add `return false` in the end of onclick. It will prevent common link behavior - reloading page.